# how can I avoid sql inject when using "order by case when" in Golang?

Tags: mysql, go, grails-orm, sql-injection

there is a param representing userName;
I need to get some sorted records,if column "starred_by" contains 'userPrefix',it should be at the front,others should be at the end.

```
var userPrefix string; //userPrefix is a Request Param.
usePrefix = `%` + userPrefix + `%`
if userPrefix != "" {
    order := fmt.Sprintf("CASE \nWHEN starred_by LIKE %q THEN 1\nELSE 2\nEND", userPrefix)
    db = db.Order(order)
}
db = db.Order(otherParam1).Order(otherParam2)
db = db.Model(***).Scan(***)
```

the raw sql likes below:

```
SELECT * FROM `***` ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN starred_by LIKE "%prefix1%" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,otherParam1,otherParam2,otherParam3
```

but apparently this causes sql inject problem , how can i fix this?

the way to solve sql inject.

Comment: Use parameter placeholders instead of fmt. MySQL uses `?` as placeholders, PostgreSQL uses `$N` positional placeholders. I don't know what gorm supports for which backend, go to their website and read the docs, it will be there somewhere either mentioned explicitly or in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

These elements cannot be bound into JDBC and gorm doesn't support them as parameterized queries or escape them - [they are dangerous to use with untrusted input](https://gorm.io/docs/security.html#SQL-injection-Methods).

There are two options to do this safely - ideally you should use both:

- Validate the columns in these via positive / whitelist validation. Each column name should be checked for existence in the associated tables.
- You should enquote the column name - adding single quotes around the columns. If you do this, you need to be careful to validate there are no quotes in the name, and error out or escape any quotes. You also need to be aware that (in most databases) adding quotes will make the name case sensitive.